# How to select all children text but excluding a tag with Scapy's XPath?

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I have this html:

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Title 1</h1><br><br>

    <h2>Sub-Title 1</h2>
    <br><br>
    Description 1.<br><br>Description 2.
    <br><br>

    <h2>Sub-Title 2</h2>
    <br><br>
    Description 1<br>Description 2<br>
    <br><br>

    <div class="infobox">
        <font style="color:#000000"><b>Information Title</b></font>
        <br><br>Long Information Text
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get all text in `<div id="content">` with XPath in Scrapy but excluding `<div class="infobox">`'s content, so the expected result is like this:

```
Title 1


Sub-Title 1


Descripton 1.

Descripton 2.


Sub-Title 2


Descripton 1.
Descripton 2.
```

But I haven't reached the excluding part yet, I'm still struggling to grab the text from the `<div id="content">`.

I have tried this:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/text()').extract()
```

But it only returns `Description 1.` and `Description 2.` from both Sub-Title.

Then I tried:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]//*/text()').extract()
```

It only returns `Title 1`, `Sub-Title 1`, `Sub-Title 2`, `Information Title`, and `Long Information Text`.

So there are two questions here:

1. How could I get all of children text from `content` div?
2. How to exclude the `infobox` div from the selection?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `descendant::` axis to find descendant text nodes, and state explicitly that the parent of those text nodes must not be a `div[@class='infobox']` element.

Turning the above into an XPath expression:

```
//div[@id = 'content']/descendant::text()[not(parent::div/@class='infobox')]
```

Then, the result is similar to (I tested with an online XPath tool) the following. As you can see, the text content of `div[@class='infobox']` does no longer appear in the result.

```
-----------------------
Title 1
-----------------------
-----------------------
Sub-Title 1
-----------------------
-----------------------
Description 1.
-----------------------
Description 2.
-----------------------
-----------------------
Sub-Title 2
-----------------------
-----------------------
Description 1
-----------------------
Description 2
-----------------------
-----------------------
-----------------------
```

**What is wrong with your approaches?**

Your first attempt:

```
//*[@id="content"]/text()
```

in plain English, means:

> Look for any element (not necessarily a `div`) anywhere in the document, that has an attribute `@id`, its value being "content". For this element, return all its *immediate child text nodes*.

Problem: You are losing the text nodes that are not an immediate child of the outer `div`, since they are inside a child element of that `div`.

---

Your second attempt:

```
//*[@id="content"]//*/text()
```

Translates to:

> Look for any element (not necessarily a `div`) anywhere in the document, that has an attribute `@id`, its value being "content". For this element, find any descendant element node and return all text nodes of that descendant element.

Problem: You are losing the immediate child text nodes of the `div`, since you are only looking at text nodes that are children of elements that are descendants of the `div`.

---

**EDIT**:

Responding to your comment:

```
//div[@id = 'content']/descendant::text()[not(ancestor::div/@class='infobox')]
```

For your future questions, please make sure the HTML you show is *representative* of your actual problems.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But your excluding solution doesn't work if `infobox` div contains another child element, see my edited html sample above.

Comment: @suud I have edited my answer. If you use `ancestor::` instead of `parent::`, the expression disregards any text inside the infobox, no matter if it's inside another element.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. What I needed was `//div[@class="body"]/descendant::text()[not(ancestor::script)]` (mentioning as an example)

Comment: Question: does it make difference to put two slashes before `descendant` instead of one slash?

Comment: @ilius The two slashes `//` are an abbreviation for the `descendant-or-self::` axis. If you meant `//div[@id = 'content']//descendant::text()[not(ancestor::div/@class='infobox')]`, no, that should not make a difference but either `//` or `descendant::` is redundant.