# Python Scrapy selector for text elements between tags

Tags: css, python-3.x, scrapy

I need to write a selector in Python Scrapy.

I want to get % of CBD and % of THC.

[image: CSS]

```py
test = productResponse
    .css('.woocommerce-product-details__short-description > p')[1]
    .get()
```

When I trying to do something like this i get result:

```
<p>
    <strong>CBD:</strong> 7.5%<br>
    <strong>THC:</strong><0.2%<br>
    <strong>Waga:</strong> 1 gram
</p>
```

But when I add the `::text` I get only the value of CBD:

```
test = productResponse
    .css('.woocommerce-product-details__short-description > p::TEXT')[1]
    .get()
```

Result:

> 7.5%

How can I get value from Strong and second text value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select all children text but excluding a tag with Scapy's XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451550/how-to-select-all-children-text-but-excluding-a-tag-with-scapys-xpath)

Comment: @Eloims, Sorry but that doesn't fix my issue. I have problem with tags not with excluding classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need classes here. I strongly recommend switching to XPath:

```
cbd = response.xpath('//strong[.="CBD:"]/following-sibling::text()[1]').get()
thc = response.xpath('//strong[.="THC:"]/following-sibling::text()[1]').get()
```